# IndexError: Array boolean indices must be concrete

Tags: numpy, jax

I'm trying to find the non-zero elements of a list using the LAX-backend implementation of `nonzero()`.

```
from jax import numpy as jnp

Gamma = [[1, 1], [1, 0]]
print(jnp.nonzero(Gamma[0]))
```

I'm receiving the error

> IndexError: Array boolean indices must be concrete.

However, I can run

```
print(np.nonzero(Gamma[0]))
```

with no issue. A [reference](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html#to-jit-or-not-to-jit) has mentioned that

> This [error] is because the function generates an array whose shape is not
> known at compile time: the size of the output depends on the values of
> the input array, and so it is not compatible with JIT.

So how should I fix this issue? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use the optional `size` and `fill_value` arguments to `jnp.nonzero` to work around this issue: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.nonzero.html

`size` lets you specify the size of the expected output to avoid dynamically-sized arrays within JIT and other transforms.

Alternatively, another common pattern if you're indexing an array with the resulting indices is to to re-express your computation using the three-argument form of [`jnp.where`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.where.html). You can read more on this at https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError under *Shape depends on Traced Value*

Without knowing more about what you are trying to do with the result, it's difficult to give any more specific advice.